# Bootstrap 5 Vertical rule width not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap row with two columns and I wanted to add a vertical divider between them. I used the `vr` class of bootstrap as follows but the width of the divider is wider than expected

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" aria-label="First name">
    </div>
    <div class="vr"></div>
    <div class="col">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" aria-label="Last name">
    </div>
</div>

<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today. I solved it by removing padding from the vr element

```
<div class="vr p-0" ></div>
```